# setState not re-rendering react component inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm trying to create a react app that adds a react component when pressing a button a then re-renders it. I'm using an array of p elements inside state as a test. The event handler function uses setState to modify the array but for some reason it does not re-renders de component so the change (the new element) is not showed in the screen. What I'm doing wrong?

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class Agenda extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.list = [];

    this.state = {

      list:[]

    };

    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);

    const items = ["Hola Mundo 1","Hola Mundo 2","Hola Mundo 3"];

    const itemComponent = items.map((item) => 
      <p>{item}</p>
    );

    this.list = itemComponent;
    this.state.list = itemComponent; 

  }

  addItem(){

    //Adds a new paragraph element at the end of the array
    this.list[3]= <p>Hola Mundo 4</p>;

    this.setState(

      {
        list: this.list
      }
    );

  }

  render(){


    return(

      <div id={this.props.id} className={this.props.className}> 


        {this.state.list}

        <button onClick={this.addItem}>

          Add item

        </button>

      </div>

    );

  }
}
```

Comment: `this.state.list = itemComponent; ` don't to this

Comment: `this.list` and `this.state.list` are references to the same array which means that you're mutating the state when you do this: `this.list[3] = ...`

Comment: @DominikMatis Ok I see the error, I will correct it and see if that solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: You should use `setState`

Comment: @Titus (Even though I should correct the error mentioned before and do not assign the state in that way) How I store a copy of it? I should use a for loop for every member of the array isn't it? but how do I select element of the array inside an object, for example:
{
  list[3]: <p>Hola Mundo 4</p>
}

Is correct?

Comment: You don't need to keep a copy of the array (see **Rajat Bhatnagar** answers) and you should probably keep strings in the state instead of components, use an array of strings and build components from it in the render function.

Answer (score 8):

There are several things you are doing which are bad practice in react. One or more of them are likely causing your problem. The issues are:

1) Don't save components in state. Your state should be just the minimum data that determines the components, and the components themselves show up in render. By storing components in state you make it easy to forget to update the state, and thus cause the rendering to not change.

2) Don't duplicate state as instance variables. By doing this, you're only forcing yourself to manually keep two pieces of data in sync with eachother. Instead, have a single source of truth, and have everything else derive from that.

3) Don't mutate state. If you want to add items to an array, create a new array which is a shallow copy of the old one, then append to that new array. React relies on state being immutable to tell whether state has changed, so mutations are an easy way to accidentally make rerendering not happen.

```
export default class Agenda extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: ['Hola Mundo 1', 'Hola Mundo 2', 'Hola Mundo 3'],
    };

    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }

  addItem() {
    this.setState((oldState) => {
      const newList = [...oldState.list];
      newList.push('Hola Mundo 4');
      return { list: newList };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id={this.props.id} className={this.props.className}>
        {this.state.list.map(item =>
          <p>{item}</p>
        )}
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>
            Add item
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.list[3]= <p>Hola Mundo 4</p>;
```

The above statement does not change the reference of the list variable. So set state doesn't see a difference while rendering. Instead do something like this -

```
this.setState({
   list: this.list.concat(<p>Hola Mundo 4</p>)
});
```